# Matplotlib interactive windows hang when pyqt is imported

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib 1.4 with the OSX backend:

```
>>> matplotlib.get_backend()
u'MacOSX'
```

If I plot anything, the window is active and healthy: I can use the zoom buttons, save, etc.  The moment I import Qt:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
```

the plot windows freeze, resulting in a spinning beach ball if I hover over them.  I can get the plot windows to update with `pl.draw()`, but I cannot interact with them.  In particular, Mac OS will no longer bring the windows to the front when activated via the Dock or apple-tab.

This is especially a problem because I am using another module that imports `PyQt4`, but I need to use that module with interactive plotting available.  Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: What happens if you switch to the `pyqt4` backend before the first plot?

Comment: Same thing (as long as I'm starting up ipython with `--matplotlib`)

Comment: What happens if you start it with `ipython --matplotlib=qt` to select the Qt4 backend at startup?

Comment: That works fine.  The problem only occurs if I start with a MacOSX backend, then import QT

Comment: FWIW I can replicate this behaviour with PyQt5 and while using the default Python shell

Answer (score 1):

Starting IPython with the `--matplotlib` argument loads and initialises `matplotlib` with the default backend that is set in your `.matplotlibrc`. There is a matplotlib limitation that you cannot switch backends once one has been loaded. This is [described in the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.use) for `use()`:

> This function must be called before importing `pyplot` for the first time; or, if you are not using `pyplot`, it must be called before importing `matplotlib.backends`.

There is an experimental `switch_backend()` but this is for [image-only backends](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend), and does not work with the Qt or MacOSX backends.

> This feature is **experimental**, and is only expected to work switching to an image backend [...] If you try to interactively switch from one GUI backend to another, you will explode.

The upshot of all this is that it is not possible to change the backend once you have started IPython with `--matplotlib` (whether or not you plot, as you confirmed). The solution is to either start with `ipython --matplotlib=qt` or change the default backend in your `.matplotlibrc` file.

On MacOSX the matplotlib config file is found in `~/.matplotlibrc/matplotlibrc`. Open that file and change the following line:

```
backend : MacOSX
```

to...

```
backend : Qt4Agg
```

Save the file, and IPython (and matplotlib) will now start up with the Qt4 backend by default when you use `ipython --matplotlib`.

More information in `.matplotlibrc` configuration is available in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but it misses the key question: I'm not trying to switch backends or even getting access to the qt backend.  The explosion is happening without an attempted switch.  Unless, perhaps, you're suggesting that importing `PyQt4` automatically attempts to switch backends?

Comment: @keflavich apologies. I got misdirected when you said that starting up with `ipython --matplotlib=qt` fixed the problem. You're quite right it *shouldn't* cause that problem just to import.

Comment: Coincidentally, I did quite a bit of work on the Qt backends for matplotlib so it may actually be a bug in my code! I'll look into it.

Comment: If you find a bug, I'll happily accept a link to the Issue as the answer.  A workaround would be nice too, but I can't really expect there to be one.

Comment: I guess the workaround is to use the Qt backend for interactive plotting (it works identically to the MacOSX one albeit with a slightly different look). From looking at it briefly I suspect it is some sort of conflict between matplotlib and Qt's event loop.

Comment: Just tested and once it freezes you *can* actually use `plt.switch_backend('Qt4Agg')` to switch to the Qt backend. Plots are destroyed so need to be re-plotted and re-shown, but they then function as normal.